# How to get an assembly location in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-assembly

I'm trying to update an outdated WPF SDK for UWP and I have this line of code:

`string path = System.Assembly.GetName().Location;`

Anyone know of something similar which is generic enough to be used in an SDK for UWP?

Comment: What is the path used for afterwards? Could you use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` for something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP you could use  `typeof(Class).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location` to get the location of specified `Assembly`.

And you could also use [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Installed­Location.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation) to get the bundle of your project.